# Проблемы с отображением c Vue компонентом и админкой Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, vuetify

Пишу свой плагин на **Wordpress**, решил админку для него сделать на **Vue.js**
В целом всё получается работает, так же решил установить для красоты **Vuetify**. Там есть компонент v-select и вот с ним возникли проблемы. Когда разрабатываю front часть вне wordpress-а - всё ок, все компоненты отображаются корректно, но после добавления приложение в сам плагин и при открытие селектора, блок с вариантом выбора сильно смещается по горизонтали и вертикале от изначального положения самого селектора.
**v-select** использует другой компонент v-menu и из него строит окно с вариантами. Там же он задаёт ему координаты по X и Y. И вот почему-то они не правильно просчитываются.

Comment: В вопросе должен быть хотябы 1 знак вопроса :)

Comment: Скриншоты бы тоже не помешали.

Comment: Так выглядит в админке WP http://joxi.ru/Vrw9L7lF4aodG2
Так с под сервера vue (npm run sereve):
1) http://joxi.ru/D2P0qPQCJawXK2 - закрытый вариант
2) http://joxi.ru/Drl9qZVFy3KQ9m - открытый

Comment: @WPPunk, как видишь stackoverflow разрешает задать вопрос без знака вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение. К `v-select` нужно добавить `prop "attach"`. В таком случае он верно начинает просчитывать положение элемента.

Comment: Dmitriev а ты хорош)